# why is class definition available in another ts file?

Tags: typescript

I am quite new to typescript and have been really confused. the most confusing problem I encounter at the moment is: why is the class definition seems to be available in another unrelated ts file in the same folder ? whenever I define a class, the tsc warns me "duplicate class definition", it is sure that by adding export keyword helps avoid it. so why is this happening? is it true that any definition without export or other modifiers becomes global or available in other ts files ? then how do i define a class to a specific scope ? I heard that by adding any modifier like export and import, tsc will treat the file like a single separate scope, is this for sure ?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

Comment: I heard that by adding any modifier like export and import, tsc will treat the file like a single separate scope, is this for sure ?

Comment: Classes in different files should not collide, no matter if they are exported or not. TS files are separate namespaces (as long as you are not using the `namespace` things, at least). What is the exact error that you get? Maybe it comes from your IDE and not the compiler?

Comment: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'xxx'

Comment: @TPReal That's not true. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html

Comment: @ritaj I don't understand why you keep giving the link to the namespaces doc, without explaining what exactly you are referring to. The question has nothing to do with namespaces, in my opinion they are unrelated. Namespaces from different files are merged, that's true, but classes declared in different files are not merged just because they use the same name (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html).

Comment: @feiyuerenhai Maybe you just edit your question to include exact content of your (minimal) files that cause problems and exact error message?

Comment: @TPReal "Conversely, a file without any top-level import or export declarations is treated as a script whose contents are available in the global scope (and therefore to modules as well)." https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html Again, what you're saying is simply not true.

Comment: File are not modules by themselves and their definitions will collide if they're not namespaced or turned into modules. Please read the links I have posted.

Comment: @ritaj thx, I think that i now come to understand the matter.